# Showing the authors username and bio on custom author.php

Tags: php, author, author-template

I have this code I'm using to create a custom author.php, which is working great to show that users posts and it's children etc:

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>


 <?php $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug',   $author_name) :     get_userdata(intval($author)); ?>


 <div class="auth-name">
 <?php if ( '' != get_the_author_meta( 'user_description' ) ) echo  apply_filters( 'archive_meta', get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' )); ?  >
 </div>

 <div class="auth-desc">
 <?php if ( '' != get_the_author_meta( 'user_description' ) ) echo    apply_filters( 'archive_meta', get_the_author_meta( 'user_description' ));   ?>
 </div>



 <div class="header">


 <h1>Buckets made (<?php $children = get_posts( array( 'author' =>  $curauth->ID, 'category_name' => 'Bucket', ) ); echo count($children);?>)  </h1>
 <a href="/add-a-bucket"><span class="big-bucket"> Add a new  bucket</span></a>
 </div>

 </div>





 <div class="content">
  <ul class="stash-container">



  <?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'bucket','post_parent' => 0 ,'author' => $curauth->ID,'posts_per_page' => -1 ); ?>
  <?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
  <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


  <li class="buckets">
   <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($site->ID); ?>">

      <div class="rollover-bucket"> 


  </div>
  </a>

  <div class="r-text"> 

  <?php do_action('gform_update_post/edit_link', array(
  'post_id' => $post->ID,
  'url'     => 'http://buckets.me/edit-bucket/',
  'text'   => 'edit', 
   ) ); ?>


   <?php echo delete_post_bucket($post->ID); ?>



   </div>



  <div class="empty-state-thumb">
  This bucket is empty!
  </div>
  <div class="display-block">



  <?php
  global $authordata, $post;
  $parent = array( 'post_type' => 'bucket','post_parent' => $post->ID,    'post_status' => 'publish' ,'author' => $curauth->ID,'posts_per_page' => -1    );
  $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'connect', true);
  $portfolio_sections = array(
 'post_type'   => 'bucket',
 'author' => $curauth->ID,
 'category_name' => 'drop',
 'orderby' => 'rand',
 'posts_per_page' => 4,
 'post_parent' => $parent, 
  'sort_order'  => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
  array(
 'key' => 'connect',
 'value' => $my_meta,
  'compare' => '=' )
  )
  );

  $sections = get_posts($portfolio_sections);
  foreach ($sections as $section) { ?>



  <img src="http://api.screenshotmachine.com/?  key=8d5e59&size=M&format=png&url=<?php echo get_post_meta($section->ID,    'the_url', true);?>">





  <?php } ?>


  </div>

  <div class="botsy">

  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
  </a>
  <div class="botsy-det">

  <?php
  $cc = get_the_content();
  if($cc != '') { ?>
  <?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 96, '...');?>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <div class="empty-lines"></div>
  <div class="empty-lines"></div>
  <div class="empty-lines"></div>
  <?php } ?>


  </div>

  </div>




  </li>




   <?php endwhile; ?>
   </ul>


   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But for some reason the username and bio are not showing at the  top, I'm pretty sure at some point during the dev process it was working fine, could it be a conflicting plugin or am I just being dumb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted as follows:

```
<div class="auth-name">
<?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>
</div>

<div class="auth-desc">
<?php echo $curauth->description; ?>
</div>
```